# Magento Extension Manager -System Upgrade - Blank page

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I had a 'Please Wait' problem on the Extension Manager and after saw the solution below and replaced the line 181, Extension Manager and System upgrade shows Blank page , I restored backup of the module.php but the problem remains and when i click on System Config keys are not being saved.

Cache flushed but same ,Magento 2.2.5

```
**setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Grid/Module.php
line 181
replace with
$item['moduleName'] = isset($item['moduleName']) ? $item['moduleName'] : $this->packageInfo->getModuleName($item['name']);**
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clean one of this directories
var/di, var/generation

Reference:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html

Answer (score 0):

I see these errors on Extension manager

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () (module-grid, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () (module-grid, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () (check-auth, line 0)

> Selected Element
>   < …
>   [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () (prolong, line 0)

Answer (score -1):

```
Var/di var/generation doesnt exist on 2.2.5
```

I think moved to generated 
Cleaned generated and compiled again,same problem